# In java, is there a way to examine how an object is still reachable from garbage collection root?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory, garbage-collection

The codebase is somewhat complex, so I was wondering if there was a tool to examine an object at runtime and determine how the JVM still sees this object as reachable.

In particular, there's one object type that I would only expect to be one instance of at a time throughout the life of the app (new ones can be created, but the old instance should be garbage collected when this happens). However, when I examine the heap, I see that multiple instances of this object type are accumulating. The class is pretty complex, so it'd be fairly time-consuming to track down what is still referencing the old object instances. Anyone know of a tool, or a way in java, to figure out why these objects can't be collected?

Comment: In IDEA while debugging you can right-click any object and push "Show referring objects", that shows you the tree down to (usually) the GC root that keeps an object alive.

Comment: I've tried that, but I have yet to find something going up the chain that seems to be the "GC root". Will there literally be something in the reference chain called like root or something?

Comment: It seems I misremembered. While IntelliJ will show you references, it doesn't do the whole "trace to garbage collection root" outside of [analyzing a memory snapshot](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-hprof-memory-snapshots.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JProfiler has such a view: You can follow the referring objects up till the root.

And it has a lot of other useful debugging views, so I've always considered it worth the price tag.

Comment: Thanks, looked into JProfiler and it did exactly what I needed! (used the free trial)

Comment: VisualVM is a free tool that has a lot of those features.